# Upgrading pip for different versions of python

Tags: python, pip

I have two versions of python installed on my computer (3.6 and 3.7).  Just upgraded pip to the latest version (19.0.1) using the command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` however i think it only upgraded the pip for python version 3.6.  When attempting to install a package specifically for python version 3.7 with the following command `pip3.7 install scipy` i got the message saying `You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.` Clearly only the pip for version 3.6 was upgraded.  I cannot figure out a command to upgrade 3.7 pip as well.  I tried the following:

```
python -m pip3.7 install --upgrade pip
```

This did not work (Trying to use the logic of how packages are handled for different versions of python).  Could not find a question that addressed this specific issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the python 3.7 interpreter to run the command:

```
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Or use the pip3.7 binary directly:

```
pip3.7 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Yes, if python3.7 is not on your PATH, you will need to use the full path to the interpreter, something like `/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 0):

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64

activate pip3

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. If you have Microsoft Visual also installed the best command to use is

```
    py -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

I used that command, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: In this case, one needs to add the option to select the Python version that should be used, such as `py -3.6 -m pip install ...` or `py -3.7 -m pip install ...`. Also it probably should read _Microsoft Windows_ (instead of _Visual_).