# Can't create a window with pygame on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame, window

This is the code

```
import pygame
background_colour = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

When I run this code on Pycharm or on idle, I get a bouncing python rocket icon on the dock (this is on MacOS), however when I run the code line by line in the terminal, the code successfully creates a pygame window. The same code works on Pycharm on windows.

Comment: Where's your `pygame.init()`?

Comment: @Rabbid76: This isn't a `pygame` installation issue, so don't close it as a dup for that reason.

Comment: yeah, I have the latest version of pygame installed successfully. Also the code works fine on windows 10, but not on Mac.

Comment: When you say "latest version of PyGame" - do you mean version 2.0.x *beta* ?

Comment: @martineau It is an installation problem. I'm very certain that Pycharm and the terminal use different installations of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have installed different versions of Python on your system (also see [Two different Python3 and Two different Python2 installations on MacOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434147/two-different-python3-and-two-different-python2-installations-on-macos-catalina)). Certainly Pycharm has its own Python version and the terminal uses a different Python installation. Therefor you can't run the code from the terminal. One way to solve the problem is to install Pygame via the terminal:

```
pip3 install pygame
```